# XMPP - Example chapter 3 "Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery" doens't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, strophe

I am just new to XMPP, and I am making the first "HELLO" code. Please take your time look at the following code (the .zip is at the end of this topic):

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Hello - Chapter 3</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#log {
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQueryUI.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/strophe.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/flXHR.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/strophe.flxhr.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hello.css"></link>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var Hello = {
        connection: null,
        log: function(msg) {
        $("#log").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
        }
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login_dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Connect to XMPP",
        buttons: {
            "Connect": function() {
                $(document).trigger("connect", {
                    jid: $("#jid").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                });
                $("#password").val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).bind("connect", function(ev, data) {
        var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
        conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function(status) {
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger("connected");
            } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger("disconnected");
            }
        });
        Hello.connection = conn;
    });

    $(document).bind("connected", function() {
        // Inform the user
        Hello.log("Connection established");
    });

    $(document).bind("disconnected", function() {
        Hello.log("Connection terminated.");
        // Remove dead connection object
        Hello.connection = null;
    });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div id="log"></div>

<!-- Login dialog -->
<div id="login_dialog" class="hidden">
<label>JID:</label><input type="text" id="jid">
<label>Pwd:</label><input type="password" id="password">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

According to the document, and the code, it must either say "Connection establised" or "Connection terminated". But it doesn't. I tried to put `alert("It runs to here!");` in every line of the code, and it still alert(). It doesn't alert anymore when I put it in bind("connected") and bind("disconnect"). So I guess the code can not run to there. I've never done it before, and there is rarely documents about this, so I don't know what to do now.

Question: Could you guys please take a look at it, and tell me what was wrong? I myself is still working on debugging it!

Extra information: These are what is in my web folder (I am afraid of missing javascript framework files). All js files are latest version.

- index.html
- scripts/

  - jQuery.js
  - jQueryUI.js
  - strophe.js
  - flensed.js
  - flXHR.js
  - flXHR.swf
  - flXHR.vbs
  - swfobject.js
  - updateplayer.swf
  - checkplayer.js
- css/

  - Not important...

Here are my code, please take time to view it: http://xx3004.kodingen.com/XMPP

I would appreciate any view of help.

[x]

Comment: Are you running this code inside from local web server ?

Answer (score 2):

your code is alright,
the problem is in the URL provided to make the connection using Strophe.

var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind");

Try to find the location of the server, otherwise install an xmpp server(vysper), locally on your machine, and change the URL as http://localhost:8080/bosh/

Also try to comment the flxhr inclusion.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. I was trying to follow the instruction in this book "Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery" and I am pretty sure that I coded everything correctly. I even test my Jabber account at "jwchat.org", and I can log in. So I guess the problem is at the sever? I'd like my project to work online, so can you recommend me a server for real-time apps and it works fine? http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind just does not work, I assume. I will try Apache Vysper. But please help me to make it online as much as possible. Thanks again. [x]

Comment: @priya i have a specific doubt about " flxhr inclusion",you have suggest to comment out  flxhr inclusion,can you tell me whats are  the reasons behind,i was facing same problem though i was using local server "localhost:5280/httpbind",when i comment out  flxhr inclusion everyting start working fine,as per book "Professional XMPP Programming" flxhr.js and its pluging for strophe is used to make cross platform calls or one have to use proxies!!!!!!so here what will be the possible reasons??

Answer (score 1):

If you are running **Openfire** on your **localhost** make sure

```
bosh_service_url =  'http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/'
```

ie

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/");
```

And if you are running **ejabberd** on your **localhost** make sure

```
bosh_service_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5222/http-bind/"
```